# Reboot device from Android application

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have made some researches, and what they say is : "Not for use by third-party applications" on the  [android permission documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REBOOT), and there is a lot of question already asked, but havent found none with a final answer,
So I was wondering, have anyone succeeded ? and may he help ? ^^

Comment: you need root permissions to do this

Comment: can you be more specific ?

Comment: how can I be any more specific, your device needs to be rooted to do this

Comment: indeed as @tyczj said if you want an app to be able to reboot a device that device will need to be rooted and the user would have to have granted your app root permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Have a `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT">` element in the proper spot in your manifest.

Step #2: Call `reboot()` on an instance of `PowerManager`.

Then, either:

Step #3a: Build your own custom build of Android, rolled into your own ROM mod. Then, sign your app with the same signing key that you used to sign the OS in the ROM mod.

or:

Step #3b: Have the user of a rooted device make your app be a system app.

Without Step #3a or #3b, your app will not be eligible to hold the `REBOOT` permission and your `reboot()` call will fail.

Comment: Seems good, and I guess I need the #3a, I can't force the user to have a rooted device ... I searched a bit about rooting the devices and as it seems every device has its own way to root, but for the custom build of android, I guess its the same for all the devices, technically in this case I am targeting the OS and not the device, right ?

Comment: @KhalilBhm: "I can't force the user to have a rooted device" -- then I fail to see how you are going to force them to install your ROM mod. "but for the custom build of android, I guess its the same for all the devices" -- um, no.

Comment: the thing is, the application will be running for a long time, do you think it's not a problem if the device just don't shut down ? not even once per day ? btw, android application yes, but not for phones.

Comment: @KhalilBhm: Hundreds of millions of Android devices routinely run for weeks without being turned off or rebooted. Users may not appreciate that your "application will be running for a long time" for other reasons, usually related to resource consumption.

Comment: Which is why exactly I need the reboot, "related to resource consumption", and its a kind of service application, so the user wont be using his device, just run the application and leave it this way, thats why I told you its not on phones, for the type of devices that are plugged to a TV.

Comment: @KhalilBhm: "and its a kind of service application" -- talented programmers can create a "service application" that does not require the computer running it to be rebooted "even once per day". For example, this Web page was served by a Web server, and if the StackOverflow servers have to be rebooted "even once per day", somebody there needs to be fired.

Comment: Point taken, with my dignity ... xD but really, what do you recommend me to do ?

Comment: @KhalilBhm: Focus on making a reliable app, and do not worry about the reboot.

Comment: even if they don't like it, Thank you for your time and advice ^^